# Ionic 2: calling function after xhr.onload

Tags: ajax, cordova, ionic2

In ionic 2, I'm using below code to upload the file(.pdf and .doc extension) into server via API. But I'm not able to call any function after **resp.success == 1** or not able to use any global variables.I'm getting error like **property doesn't exist on type xmlhttpeventtarget** As I want to navigate user to next page on successful submission of the file I need call some function inside success.

```
        xhr.open('POST', "myurl", true);
      xhr.onload = function() {


        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
          console.log('Server got: in IOS ', resp);
          console.log('Server got: in IOS ', resp.message);

            if(resp.success == 1)
            {
              console.log("THIS IS SUCCESS")     

            }
            else{
              alert(resp.message)
              return
            }

          };
     }


      xhr.send(this.fd);
```

Comment: Which property does not exists? Please provide the full error stack trace. By the way, if you are usinbg Ionic 2, why don't you use Angular 2' Http Client (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) that abstract the implementation for client-server communication via http?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I could solve this by declaring a variable which is initialised to this ex: var self = this; then I was able to use all the functions and global variables with self.function_name and self.variable_name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to solve this would be by using **arrow functions** like this:

```
  xhr.open('POST', "myurl", true);
  xhr.onload = () => {

    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
      console.log('Server got: in IOS ', resp);
      console.log('Server got: in IOS ', resp.message);

        if(resp.success == 1) {
          console.log("THIS IS SUCCESS");

          // Now 'this' points to the component :) !!
          this.yourcustomfunction(); 
          this.yourvariableblename;

        } else{
          alert(resp.message)
          return
        }

      };
 }

 xhr.send(this.fd);
```

Notice that now we do

```
xhr.onload = () => {...});
```

instead of

```
xhr.onload = function() {...});
```

By using arrow functions, **the `this` property is not overwritten and still references the component instance** (otherwise, the this keyword points to the inner function, and your custom method and variable are not defined in it).

Comment: Yea, it works.thanks for the help. Your solution is very efficient

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found solution to this problem.By creating a variable which has **this** reference,  the snippet is as below.

```
    var self = this;
    xhr.open('POST', "myurl", true);
  xhr.onload = function() {


    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
      console.log('Server got: in IOS ', resp);
      console.log('Server got: in IOS ', resp.message);

        if(resp.success == 1)
        {
          console.log("THIS IS SUCCESS")     
          self.yourcustomfunction()
          self.yourvariableblename
        }
        else{
          alert(resp.message)
          return
        }

      };
 }


  xhr.send(this.fd);
```